# AWS IAM: Is this a Resource or Identity based policy?

Tags: amazon-iam

According to this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_grammar.html#policies-grammar-bnf

> The principal_block element is required in resource-based policies (for example, in Amazon S3 bucket policies) and in trust policies for IAM roles. It must not be included in identity-based policies.

so is this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws-dates.html

an Identity-based Policy?

Comment: you can create the roles with specific Policies attached to it and then can add up the users to that policies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we agree! The example policy you linked to is an identity-based policy.  The policy does not contain a principal element.
To review, a principal is the entity that is allowed or denied access to a resource.

When you attach the policy to an IAM user, that user becomes the principal. 
Therefore, in an identity-based policy the principal is not explicitly declared in the policy statement.

Here´s a quote from the AWS documentation, "In those cases [policies that 
you attach to IAM users] , the principal is implicitly the user that 
the policy is attached to (for IAM users)..." 
(For more information, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_principal.html)